# What is the term for "conveying information to a user efficiently"

Tags: website-design, gui-design

I am having trouble even googling this concept. I want to learn more about it.

The general idea is how efficiently a website or an individual webpage conveys information to a user.

For example this is good: https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/k/kendrho01.shtml
because you arrive and immediately can see a ton of stats.

This is worse: https://www.mlb.com/player/howie-kendrick-435062
because of the spacing, needing to click stupid tabs that autoscroll you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a broad question that covers a number of different aspects, so I won't go into detail here. However, these are some general areas that will hopefully help with initial research and reading for you.

In terms of Information Architecture, conveying information to a user efficiently involves the effective use of chunking to group information into logical sections, and then creating a consistent flow through the different sections depending on audience or intent.

In terms of visual design, conveying information to a user efficiently involves creating clear visual hierarchy by spacing, density of content (words per line, paragraphs per page) as well as more complex design assets like charts, graphs and infographics.

In terms of user engagement, conveying information to a user efficiently involves using narratives or helping the user to explore or understand the content better by the language, tone of voice and the way the content is written to help users retain the data or information being conveyed.

I think that will probably be enough for you to start delving into things further, and if you have more specific questions please post another question.

Answer (score 1):

You could search for content related to "information density" and/or "data density" in the context of user experience or interface design. You'll find that there is a balance depending on the product and the audience and certain users will prefer more information/data while others might become overwhelmed.

It's helpful to think about how these design decisions impact the "cognitive load" of a user.